# Hundreds of event ID 14554 DfsSvc related

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

i'm experiencing a lot of those errors in the event viewer

Namespace DFS Service : initialization of the shared folder that houses the root of the namespace is completed . Shared folder : foldername

Eventi ID: 14554

The origin of this event is DfsSvc.

I've googled this event id for the whole day and I didn't find anything...

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like this only happens in Windows 2012R2.  I also noticed that every other event has uppercase and lowercase for the first letter of the namespace.  I think there's a case sensitivity bug going on...